# Post RestSharp Google API Error

Tags: json, google-api, restsharp

I'm trying to access YouTube API using RestSharp.
While POSTing I'm getting error code:400 with the following reason:
"This API does not support parsing form-encoded input".
Below is a short snippet of my code:

```
var client = new RestClient("https://www.googleapis.com");
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
request.Resource = "youtube/v3/liveBroadcasts";
request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
request.AddParameter("part", "snippet,status");
request.AddParameter("key", "MyClientId");
request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + "MyAccessCode");
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
request.AddBody(aJson);

try
{
var response = client.Execute(request);
Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
Console.WriteLine(e);
}
```

The response content as describe above was "This API does not support parsing form-encoded input"
In the Json that I'm sending (aJson) looks like that:

```
{
"snippet": {
"scheduledEndTime": "2015-01-10T12:11:11.0+0400",
"scheduledStartTime": "2015-01-10T11:11:11.0+0400",
"title": "MyBroadcastName"
},
"kind": "youtube#liveBroadcast",
"status": {
"privacyStatus": "private"
}
}
```

I'll be glad to get any assistance related to the above request.
What am I doing wrong?

thanks,
R.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Todd and after some additional digging I found the problem.
below is the fixed code:

```
var client = new RestClient("https://www.googleapis.com");
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
request.Resource = "youtube/v3/liveBroadcasts?part={part}&key={key}";
request.AddParameter("part", "snippet,status", ParameterType.UrlSegment);
request.AddParameter("key", "MyClientId", ParameterType.UrlSegment);
request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + "MyAccessCode");
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
request.AddBody(anObject); //<== Here you should use an object and NOT a json. RestSharp will do the serialization!

try
{
var response = client.Execute(request);
Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
Console.WriteLine(e);
}
```

Thanks for your assistance.
R.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is with your calls to `request.AddParameter`. You want those appended the URL as query parameters, but when the HTTP method is POST, RestSharp will send them as URL-encoded form data by default. You want something like this:

```
request.Resource = "youtube/v3/liveBroadcasts?part={part}&key={key}";
request.AddParameter("part", "snippet,status", ParameterType.UrlSegment);
request.AddParameter("key", "MyClientId", ParameterType.UrlSegment);
```